# Chart.js Plot Diagonal lines on top right and limit the lines going out of the chart

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to plot the diagonal lines between two points as shown in the below image, but the lines are going beyond the chart area in the bottom and top end is empty.

[image]

CodeSandBox here
https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-dawn-nhcvjq?file=/App.tsx

How to make the lines not go beyond the x-axis, also the calculations to fill the top end area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I resolved it by myself,Now the new graph with the horizontal line between two x axis point looks like below.
[image]

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-dawn-nhcvjq?file=/App.tsx